# Color bars based on axis text, not data point value - EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My code below changes the bar color based on the data point label value, but i have several points with the same value and I only want the one with text to be colored. How can I modify the code to color based on axis text?

```
x1 = ws2.Cells(icounter, 3)
Set ch = ActiveChart
Set s = ch.SeriesCollection(1)


nPoint = s.Points.Count
For iPoint = 1 To nPoint
If Format(x1, "0.00%") = s.Points(iPoint).DataLabel.Text Then
s.Points(iPoint).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
End If
Next iPoint
```

for example, in picture below, bars other than "bK EMEA ce" is colored because those bars have the same data point value as bk emea ce. I only want bk emea ce colored red

[image: for example, in picture below, bars other than "bK EMEA ce" is colored because those bars have the same data point value as bk emea ce. I only want bk emea ce colored red]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Swap

```
If Format(x1, "0.00%") = s.Points(iPoint).DataLabel.Text Then
```

for

```
If ws2.Cells(icounter, 2) = s.XValues(iPoint) Then
```